# Calculating pow(x, y) when one value is fixed

Tags: c++, floating-point, numeric, numerical-methods, pow

Consider the calculation of [`pow(x, y)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) for `double` values. We can assume that standard library implementations are relatively efficient for the case where both `x` and `y` vary arbitrarily, but how about the case where where either `x` or `y` are fixed for a large number of calls to `pow`?

How can we take advantage of this fact to speed up evaluation, e.g., by hoisting out work which depends only the fixed parameter, so that is only done once?

Note that the fixed values are not known at compile-time, but at runtime, so any compile-time analysis isn't useful.

Comment: You mean if computed as `exp(y*log(x))` that one only needs to compute `log(x)` once if `x` is fixed? That is in general not possible as the library implementation of `pow` follows an extended decision tree with cases for easy powers and simplifications for higher accuracy in corner cases.

Comment: If `x` is fixed, you can precompute `log(x)` as a double-`double`, giving a head-tail pair of `double` numbers `log_hi`, `log_lo`. Multiply with `y` to produce a double-`double` product `prod_hi`, `prod_lo`. Now compute `r = exp (prod_hi); r = fma (prod_lo, r, r);` With a faithfully-rounded `exp()` implementation, maximum error should be < 2 ulps. Cost would be cost of `exp()` plus cost of about ten FMA instructions. Note that this does *not* take care of numerous special cases defined for `pow()`.

Comment: Curious: About "how about the case where where either x or y are fixed", what are some of the fixed values of those cases and what range of the other?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we take advantage of this fact to speed up evaluation, e.g., by hoisting out work which depends only the fixed parameter, so that is only done once?

Yes, you may achieve correct and  faster results if you are well versed in math and floating point, some compiler knowledge, and exploit application use on a limited range of the remaining variable `x` or `y`.

Else like the other 99.9% of coders, realize such code is likely a little wrong in many cases, greatly wrong in special cases and even if faster on one platform, not certainly so in a portable sense.

Various compilers analyse `pow(x,y)` and will emit efficient code with select constants.  Consider allowing the compiler to do its job and if still in doubt, profile against your best attempt and see what gains are had. The tricky part of testing your code will be to see how much precision you lost.

---

Given OP's additional info, some ideas:

`pow(x,y)` is *mathematically* as `exp(y*log(x))` with infinite precision and when `x > 0`.

Let `double u = y*log(x)`.
With C code, `pow(x,y)` is more like `exp(u + u_err)`, where `u_err` is the accumulated error of the `log()`, multiplication and finite precision of `double`.

The error in the result of `v = exp(u + u_err)` is *very sensitive* to the magnitude of `u`.  When `u` is [-1…1], `u_err` makes little difference.  When `|u|` is 10, `u_err` eats away at the 11 or so LSBits of `v`.
Good `pow()` handles this loss with extra internal precision.

---

**If precision loss is a concern**

To successfully manage precision loss, the first step is to use `exp2(), log2()` instead of `exp(), log()`.  Base 2 tends to be faster and at least select results are exact.
If `x` is “fixed” and `x > 0`, we could pre-calculate `xlog2 = log2(x)` and then later repetitively use `exp2(y * xlog2)`.
Also we could take advantage of extra precision of `long double`, when it exist.

`long double` vs. `double` cost performance in at least 3 places:

- `log2l(x)`, a one time cost.
- `xlog2l * y` to reduce `u_error`.
- `exp2l(u)` to reduce computational error or just `exp2()` if `|u| < 1`.

  ```
  // Using `long double` to help maintain precession    
  void pow_x_pos_fixed(size_t n, double x, const double *y, double *xy) {
    assert(x > 0);
    long double xlog2l = log2l(x);  // Using long double here is a one time cost
    for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      long double u = xlog2l * y;
      xy[i] = (double) exp2l(u); 
    }
  }
  ```

In the end, I suspect the above may not be much faster than `pow(x,y)` and so the only real faster approaches loss precision.  In that case is tolerable, also consider `powf((float)x, (float)y))`.

Comment: Note that the values are not _fixed_ in the sense of compile time constants, but fixed as in `pow` will be calculated thousands or millions of time with the same `x` or `y`, but that is still a runtime value. I tried to make this clear in the question, but I have another shot.

Comment: @BeeOnRope  The first 2/3 of this answer apply to a constant `x` or `y` as well as to a _fixed_ one.  You might get faster results when the _fixed_ value is of a limited domain, but otherwise your are looking for  an analysis  of dozens of cases with `pow()` - a bit broad.  Look at the [error handling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) alone,  Such user C code is unlikely to generally handle the entire domain of the non-_fixed_ variable faster (and still accurate) than crafted asm code of `pow(x,y)`.

Comment: the problem is the first two paragraphs don't make a good answer. They boil down to "yes you can" and "don't do it". Both would be better as a comment.

Comment: @BeeOnRope The posted question "Can we take advantage ..." certainly sounds like a Y/N one and not a "how".  To provides deeper examples on how, please provide some examples case usages to improve the focus.

Comment: Fair enough, I meant it has a "how" not a "can we, yes/no?" or "is it a good idea for the 99% to attempt", although admittedly maybe it wasn't clear from the text (I've adjusted it a bit). I might flesh it out with a specific example and some typical input ranges later on.